# Find the smallest positive integer such that $b^{|b|}=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group $G$ with the identity element $e$ such that: $a,b \neq e,$ $a^2=e$ and $aba=b^2.$ Find the smallest *positive* integer |$ b $| such that $b^{|b|}=e$. Prove the answer is correct.

---

I keep multiplying but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to get to. Is |$b$| the same as $b$ but positive? I'm confused

Comment: $|b|$ is called the order of $b$, denoted by $|b|$ or $order(b)$. It has nothing to do with the absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $aba=b^2$, we get both $ab = b^2a$ and $ba = ab^2$.  Putting these together, we get $ba^2b = ab^4a$ or $b^2 = ab^4a$.  But then, substituting into the first equation, $aba = ab^4a$, so $b^3=e$.  Since the order of $b$ divides $3$, $3$ is prime, and the order of $b$ is not $1$, the order of $b$ is $3$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$b^4=(b^2)^2=(aba)^2=(aba)(aba)=(ab)(aa)(ba)= (ab)(ba)=a(bb)a=a(aba)a=(aa)b(aa)=b$$
Hence, $b^3=e$. Since $b\neq e$, you only have to discard that $b^2=e$ and I think this is easy from the relation $aba=b^2$.

Comment: Alternatively (for the last step), if $b^3 = e$ and $b^2 = e$, then $b = e$

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't see that. Thanks